# Relationship of acids and bases with pH. (Proportional Relationship)

Tags: acid-base, concentration, hydrogen, oxygen

Can someone please clarify the relationship between acidic-basic strength and pH? I have come across conflicting information and am unsure about the correct understanding.

Some people including my chemistry teacher say that

$\text{Acidic Strength} ∝ \frac{1}{pH}  
\\
\text{Basic Strength} ∝ pH$

> According to my research, it's called **proportional relationship**.
> Well, I'm asking whether this information is accurate or not. If not? show me the correct one.

Comment: Express the relations quantitatively and decide yourself. E.g. the simplified equation for weak acid is pH=0.5(pKa - log c), for weak base pH= 14 - 0.5(pKb - log c).

Comment: There is either a wrong terminology at play, or something lost in translation/definition.  pH is not how [acidic/basic strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_strength) is quantified at all.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In pH p stands for "potenz" Which means taking negative logarithm of active mass of hydronium ion  $$ pH = -log(a) $$ where a is the active mass of hydronium ions.
As we know that the acidic strength increases with the increase of active mass of hydronium ions the negative logarithm of active mass i.e., pH should decrease with acidic strength.
Therefore,$$Acidic Strength ∝ 1/pH  And  Basic Strength ∝ pH$$

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: Nothing written here is coherent or correct from the point of logic, formatting or facts, and does not address the main point (flaw) in OP's question at all.

Comment: The p for pH as $Potenz$ is nothing but a common myth.